# JQPLOT- setting graph type programmatically

Tags: jqplot

I want to set the type of graph programaticaly.
So, instead of using, for example, this in seriesDefaults:
`renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,`
I want to use `renderer:$.jqplot.graphtype,` where graphtype has been set to BarRenderer, LineRenderer etc.
But it does not work in whatever format I use graphtype (always defaults to default line graph). Advice on passing this value appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting an option like this `renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer` in your options already is a programmatical way of doing it.

Presumably, you're trying to change this value depending on a text variable (as opposed to a reference to an object like `$.jqplot.BarRenderer`).

You don't have to define this when you define your options. You could do this later, based on a default set of options. For example:

```
var myDefaultOptions = {
    seriesDefaults:{
        pointLabels: { show: true }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    },
    highlighter: { show: false }
}

// ...

// Note: $.extend(true, ...) for a deep copy, if you're re-using this later.
var myOptions = $.extend(true, {}, myDefaultOptions);

if (graphType == 'bars') {
    myOptions.seriesDefaults.renderer = $.jqplot.BarRenderer;
} else if (graphType == '...') {
    // Other renderer
}

var plot = $.jqplot('chart1', data, myOptions);
```

Using this might also give you the opportunity to change other settings that may make more sense depending on the graph type (whether it makes sense to zoom, highlight, ...).

If you want to do this for specific series, you should first create an empty `series: {}` in your default options, it will make it easier to set individual options there (accessing each series with a number).